# SQL Server: How to check a time period whether falls in a period and deduct out the time interval?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, time, dateadd

Good day All.

My task is to check whether the times fall in into the breaktime period. If yes, I deduct out the break time.

Since the breaktimes are different for different periods, I do use Date X to check which break time to use for calculation.

The parameter I passed in are  Time A (2019-11-28 10:30:00.000), Time B (2019-11-28 11:30:00.000) and Date X (20191128)

In my database, there are

> •Effective From, VARCHAR(YYYYMMDD, 20191127)
>
> •Effective To, VARCHAR(YYYYMMDD, 20191131)
>
> •Break Time 1 Start Time, VARCHAR (HHMMSS, 104500)
>
> •Break Time 1 Duration, INT (30) ... till Break time N.

I don't have a column named **Break Time n End Time** which I need to determine myself by adding Break Time n Duration to Break Time n Start.

So far what I have tried is to

> •convert 104500 to 10:45:00 using left, substring and right function
>
> •add 30 minutes using DATEADD(minutes, 30, 10:45:00)

But the return is `1990-01-01 11:15:00.000`

I can't compare `1990-01-01 11:15:00.000` with `2019-11-28 10:30:00.000` to check and calculate the time interval.

Any suggestions to overcome this? Really appreciate.

Comment: please show your current query and not just psedo code

Comment: SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, (select convert(varchar, (select left('104500',2)+ ':' + SUBSTRING('104500',3,2) + ':' + right('104500',2)), 8)))
It returns 1900-01-01 11:15:00.000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cast` it as `time` so you can compare.

```
select cast('2019-11-28 10:30:00.000' as time), cast('1990-01-01 11:15:00.000' as time)
```

**Output:**

[image]

**adding your time to your date.**

```
declare @time varchar(10) ='104500' 
select cast(concat(cast('20191127' as date), ' ', left(@time,2)+ ':' + substring(@time,3,2) + ':' + right(@time,2)) as datetime)
```

Comment: May I know how to add my date 2019-11-28 (from 20191128 VARCHAR) to my dateadd query? So that it doesn't return 1900-01-01 to me

Comment: This is my dateadd query which returns me 1900-01-01 11:15:00.00  : SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, (select convert(varchar, (select left('104500',2)+ ':' + SUBSTRING('104500',3,2) + ':' + right('104500',2)), 8)))